# How to add conditional insert statements in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like this

```
insert into states(state_name,cust_id)
select 'Sleeping',customer.cust_id from customer;
```

I have a states table and customer table, for each customer i want to insert a row in the states table with state as 'Sleeping'.

Lets say i have three rows in the customer table , the above query will insert three rows in the states table with corresponding cust_id's from the customer table.

Now , In this query i just want to make sure that i insert only if that state is not existing in the table. I am currently stuck here and not sure how i put that check here in this query . Can anyone help me  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `merge` instead:

```
merge into states s
  using customer c
  on (    c.cust_id = s.cust_id
      and s.state_name =' Sleeping')
when not matched then insert (state_name, cust_id)
  values ('Sleeping', c.cust_id);
```

Comment: your answer worked but with a minor edit  on (c.cust_id = s.cust_id AND s.state_name =' Sleeping')

Could you add this ?

Comment: Sure; added into code I previously posted.